# AndEngine ButtonSprite OnClick or OnTouch

Tags: android, button, andengine, sprite, onclicklistener

When I touch a button (click) the button changes it state to pressed or ACTION_DOWN, and the image changes, but if I perform a "drag" (I don't want to drag the button, I just simply move my finger out of the button focus but without releasing it) the state continues ACTION_DOWN/PRESSED and the image/texture continues the same "pressed.png"

Is there any work around? I just want a behaviour identically to View.OnClick()/On.Touch where this situation doesn't happen.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could prolly do something like `ACTION_MOVE: return;`

Comment: I'm looking at ButtonSprite.onAreaTouched and I've noticed that MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE/ACTION_CANCEL is never called/detected... that's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
setTouchAreaBindingOnActionMoveEnabled(true);
```